# Is there a way to do a login redirect immediately when the SPA is accessed?

Tags: javascript, html, azure, single-page-application, azure-ad-msal

I have created an SPA. Refer to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-spa-app).

So, accessing the SPA and pressing the [SignIn] button will take you to the login screen. And if the authentication is successful, you will be redirected to SPA again.This is a common process.
However, I would like to see the login page from the moment I access the SPA.

In other words, we want to display the login page from the beginning without pressing the [SignIN] button and without firing the onclick event.
In the sample, the following process is executed after the button is clicked.

```
function signIn() {

    myMSALObj.loginRedirect(loginRequest);
}
```

Is it possible to execute this function at the moment the URL is opened and display the login screen to the user?
I found out that there is something called "onload" and tried to use it, but it did not work.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using any framework e.g. React to develop the SPA?

Comment: yes,My SPA is built in React.
The sample I included is not React, but I use React in my own SPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want your entire application protected by Azure AD authentication. If that's the case, then what you can do is wrap your entire application inside [`<MsalAuthenticationTemplate>`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-react/docs/getting-started.md#msalauthenticationtemplate-component).

This component will ensure that a user must be signed-in before accessing the application.

Here's a code sample taken from this [`link`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-react/docs/getting-started.md#msalauthenticationtemplate-component):

```
import React from "react";
import { MsalAuthenticationTemplate } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { InteractionType } from "@azure/msal-browser";

function ErrorComponent({error}) {
    return <p>An Error Occurred: {error}</p>;
}

function LoadingComponent() {
    return <p>Authentication in progress...</p>;
}

export function Example() {
    const authRequest = {
        scopes: ["openid", "profile"]
    };

    return (
        // authenticationRequest, errorComponent and loadingComponent props are optional
        <MsalAuthenticationTemplate 
            interactionType={InteractionType.Popup} 
            authenticationRequest={authRequest} 
            errorComponent={ErrorComponent} 
            loadingComponent={LoadingComponent}
        >
            <p>At least one account is signed in!</p>
        </MsalAuthenticationTemplate>
      )
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I can't try it because I don't always have the SPA at hand right now, but from what I've researched, does that mean it works as follows?
[Pattern 1: User is not logged in]
①Access the SPA URL (ex:http://localhost:6420) → ②login screen is displayed to the user (function signIn() in the sample is executed) → ③if the authentication is successful, the SPA is displayed after authentication.
[Pattern 2: If the user is logged in]
①Access the SPA URL (ex:http://localhost:6420) → ②You are authenticated, so you will be redirected to the SPA after authentication

Comment: If the user is not authenticated, they are automatically redirected to Azure AD for authentication. If the user is authenticated, they are shown the application.

Comment: Sorry again and again. Please let me know so I can clarify the procedure.
You said "AUTOMATICALLY REDIRECTED to Azure ad (or b2C too?)." 
So you are saying that the user does not need to press the [SignIn] button?
Please excuse my poor English.

Comment: That’s correct and there’s absolutely no need to apologize .

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details!
I learned a lot.
I will try to develop this again later for reference, so I will keep this question open until then.
I'll close it once it's resolved, but if I run into any problems, let me know!

Comment: Hi!
I have tried several of the methods you have taught me, but they do not work. I think it is because I am not a good programmer. Are there any other websites besides the code you taught me that would be helpful (like sample code, for example)?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you’ve tried and the issues you’re running into. GitHub repository for MSAL is the best place for code samples.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.I gave my code to gituhub.
[link](https://github.com/pepepepe-pe/temp)
When I "npm start" now, nothing appears and I don't go to the login page or the authenticated page.
And, When I set authConfig to [link](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/samples/msal-react-samples/typescript-sample/src/authConfig.ts), the screen transition worked correctly.
In other words, is the ADB2C application set up incorrectly?
Sorry for the poor explanation, but thank you in advance.